# How to Restore MongoDB Database After Having Deleted DB Files From Directory

Tags: mongodb, restore, recovery, mongodb2.6

I'm running MongoDB 2.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 and I accidentally deleted db file in `/var/lib/mongodb`.

I cannot restart the MongoDB instance:

```
mongo: error SEVERE: unable to open file number 5.
```

If I purge and re-install will I be able to restore the data? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do u have any recent backups?

Comment: no, I only have 4 of 6 files located in /var/lib/mongodb... bm.0, bm.1, bm.2, bm.3 I have deleted .4 and .5

Comment: Is your goal just to get your MongoDB deployment back online or are you looking for suggestions on how to try to recover data in the deleted files first? I expect AskUbuntu or ServerFault would be better StackExchange sites to ask about recovering deleted data. Recovery/salvage options may be limited depending on your filesystem and any write activity that has happened on your data volume since the files were deleted.

Comment: You should be able to get your MongoDB 2.6 deployment to a working state (but without the contents of the missing files) using [`mongod --repair `](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/) to rebuild your data files. If you do manage to recover/undelete files, you should still run repair to ensure data integrity. Note that with the [MMAP storage engine](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/#mmapv1) (as used in MongoDB 2.6) the repair command requires free disk space equal to the size of your current data set plus 2 gigabytes.

Answer (score 1):

## 3-rd Party Tool

You might want to consider recovering the files using the PhotoRec tool.

***Reference:*** [PhotoRec Homepage](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)

> PhotoRec is file data recovery software designed to recover lost files including video, documents and archives from hard disks, CD-ROMs, and lost pictures (thus the Photo Recovery name) from digital camera memory. PhotoRec ignores the file system and goes after the underlying data, so it will still work even if your media's file system has been severely damaged or reformatted.

### Prerequisites

First of all you will have to ensure that no more writes are performed against the disk in your Ubuntu system, otherwise you might be overwriting the deleted files.

### Step by Step Guide

Then you can consider following the step by step instructions provided on their website.

> This Recovery example guides you through PhotoRec step by step to recover deleted files or lost data from a reformatted partition or corrupted file system. For lost/deleted partitions or deleted files from a FAT or NTFS file system, try TestDisk first - it's usually faster and TestDisk can retrieved the original file names. Translations of this PhotoRec manual to other languages are welcome.
>
> ...
>
> Under Unix/Linux/BSD, you need to be root to run PhotoRec (ie. `sudo testdisk-6.13/photorec_static`)

***Reference:*** [PhotoRec Step By Step](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step)

#### Short Quick Version

1. Start PhotoRec from a USB medium or other disk than where your database files reside.
2. Select disk.
3. Hit <kbd>Proceed</kbd>
4. Select partition.
5. Hit either
    a. <kbd>Search</kbd>
    b. <kbd>Options</kbd>
    c. <kbd>File Opt</kbd>
    d. <kbd>Quit</kbd> (well not really, unless you are unsure)
6. After hitting <kbd>Search</kbd> the tool will try and to determine the file system. If you know your filesystem type, select the appropriate one.
7. Select either the <kbd>Free</kbd> space option or the <kbd>Whole</kbd> option depending on your requirements.
8. Select where your recovered files should be copied to.

   > Tip: Copying to another drive (USB, eSata, other disk than where the database resides) will increase the probability of not destroying the file you are trying to recover.
9. Hope that the files are displayed as recovered in the summary.

The files on your disk might have already been overwritten and unrecoverable. But good luck anyway.

> **Disclaimer**
>   I am in not way affiliated with PhotoRec or any of its employees.
>   **No guarantee given** that the provided solution will result in recoverable files. **You are trying this procedure at your own risk.**

---

## Future Considerations

1. Implement a backup solution (script/3-rd party tool/...)
2. Test your backup solution
3. Test a restore of database backup which were created with the backup solution

***Reference:*** [MongoDB Backup Methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/) (MongoDB Site)

Comment: Although PhotoRec has broad support for recovering deleted files, MongoDB does not currently appear to be amongst the [File Formats Recovered by PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec). I suspect recovery options would be limited to a filesystem undelete tool like TestDisk (mentioned as part of your answer, but not the focus).

Comment: You would be amazed what PhotoRec is capable of even though not listed.